# How to make axios call within callback of setState callback

Tags: javascript

I have two async call as follows. I try to wrap the axios call within the callback of `this.setState`, but It throws syntax error like `, expected`

```
      this.setState(prevState => ({ 
          condition: [...prevState.condition, { name: "readByGroup", operator: "IN  ", value: groups }]
        }))
      }

        this.props.getMetricsByContent(this.state.condition).then((data) => {
          this.setState({isLoader: false});
          if(data && Array.isArray(data) && data.length > 0){
            let csvContent = papa.unparse(data);
            this.download(csvContent, 'metrics.csv', 'text/csv;encoding:utf-8');
            this.setState({statusMsg: "File Downloaded successfully"})
          } else this.setState({statusMsg: "No records to download"})
        })
```

What I tried is given below:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({ 
      condition: [...prevState.condition, { name: "readByGroup", operator: "IN  ", value: groups }]

      this.props.getMetricsByContent(this.state.condition).then((data) => {
        this.setState({isLoader: false});
        if(data && Array.isArray(data) && data.length > 0){
          let csvContent = papa.unparse(data);
          this.download(csvContent, 'metrics.csv', 'text/csv;encoding:utf-8');
          this.setState({statusMsg: "File Downloaded successfully"})
        } else this.setState({statusMsg: "No records to download"})
      })
}))
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where you're running a callback function in the this.setState.

Try:

```
   this.setState(prevState => ({ 
          condition: [...prevState.condition, { name: "readByGroup", operator: "IN  ", value: groups }]
    }),  () => {
     this.props.getMetricsByContent(this.state.condition).then((data) => {
            this.setState({isLoader: false});
            if(data && Array.isArray(data) && data.length > 0){
              let csvContent = papa.unparse(data);
              this.download(csvContent, 'metrics.csv', 'text/csv;encoding:utf-8');
              this.setState({statusMsg: "File Downloaded successfully"})
            } else this.setState({statusMsg: "No records to download"})
          }))
   }
```

The key being the arrow function as the next paramater to setState.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate